# How to get the classpath of a Java application running on webstart?

Tags: java, classpath, java-web-start

My Java application, deployed via webstart, invokes a helper application.  I want to start the helper application in a separate JVM with the the *same* classpath as the main application.

*Without* webstart, the system `ClassLoader` provides an answer.  *With* webstart, the system `ClassLoader` provides the path to `deploy.jar` only.

I found [this](https://community.oracle.com/message/5503117#5503117), but it seems to be out of date.  It refers to at least one method on internal API `com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache` that has since vanished from Java 8u60.  Perhaps there is another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that works (in Jython) with Java 8u66.  Obviously, I would prefer a solution that does not depend upon internal APIs.  But, perhaps that is not available.

```
import com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache as Cache
import traceback
classPath = []
for indexFile in Cache.getCacheEntries(False):
    try:
        cacheEntry = Cache.getCacheEntryFromFile(indexFile)
        jarFile = cacheEntry.getJarFile()
        if jarFile is not None:
            classPath.append(jarFile.getName())
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, but searching the cache will only work for as long as a new update of the jws application is not downloaded. The classpath will contain references to all directories with old and new versions.

I use a C++-dll for this purpose called from the jws application

```
HMODULE thisDll = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("MyDll.dll"));
    ::GetModuleFileName(thisDll, currentDir, sizeof(currentDir));
_splitpath(currentDir, Ldrive, Ldirpath, Lfname, Lext);
sprintf(currentDir,"%s%s",Ldrive,Ldirpath);
```

After that I parse currentDir to find all jar files.